# Access a method of an object that is inside another object

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I have a class Connection that has an object $db_connection (a PDO object). Then i have a Consultant connection that has a Connection object. I want to access a method of the $db_connection object trough a method of the class Consultant. I tried this :

```
$statement=$this->connection->db_connection->prepare($sqlQuery);
```

I have an error saying that Im trying to get property of non-object.

Connection class code:

```
require('config.php');

class Connection{

    public $db_connection;

    public function __construct(){

        try{

            $this->db_connection = new PDO("mysql:host=".host."; dbname=".db_name,user,pass);
            $this->db_connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $this->db_connection->exec("SET CHARACTER SET ".character_set);


        }
        catch(Exception $e){

            echo "<br>Error at line:".$e->getLine()."<br>";

        }   

    }

}
```

Class Consultant code:

```
require("Connection.php");

class Consultant{

    private $connection;

    function __construct(){

        $connection = new Connection();

    }

    public function getAllProducts(){


        $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS;";

        $statement=$this->connection->db_connection->prepare($sqlQuery); //HERE IS THE ERROR LINE!!!!!!!!   

        $statement->execute(array());

        $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $statement->closeCursor();

        $this->db_connection = NULL;

        return $result;

    }
```

Comment: What's the value of `$this->db_connection` after `$this->db_connection->exec("SET CHARACTER SET ".character_set);`?

Comment: `$connection = new Connection();` needs to use `$this->connection`.

Answer (score 0):

In short, the Consultant class, you need to make $connection a true property in the class.

---

```
class Consultant{

    private $connection;

    function __construct(){

   // $connection = new Connection();
   //**** Answer *****
   $this->connection = new Connection();

}

public function getAllProducts(){
    $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS;";

    $statement=$this->connection->db_connection->prepare($sqlQuery);   

      ......
}
```